# IntelliJ Refactor Hungarian / mNotation out of a project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-15

By far the best safest way to refactor a variable name that I've found is in an IDE like IntelliJ. It's ability to change a member variable and resolve any naming conflicts in Java between member variables and local variables is beyond the scope of any simple renaming script that I or someone else could write.

Is there an existing way in IntelliJ / IntelliJ plugin to refactor Hungarian Notation out of a project / source set?

Comment: Have you tested this [HungarianInspection](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7818-hungarianinspection)?